# Internet Explorer save or open blob results in incomplete wav file

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, wav, data-uri

I have a base64 encoded .wav file. When I try to download the file in IE11, the download appears to be successful but it is not. I can hear the first half a second or so but then it stops.

In other browsers the file that downloads is 78KB but in IE it's 3.73KB.

Am I missing a step somewhere in here? I can provide the base64 encoded file if required.

EDIT: Plus a [link](http://pastebin.com/qj7rVPZF) to the base64 encoded .wav file

```
download: function(data, filename){
    var binary = atob(data);
    var array = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < binary.length; i++) {
        array.push(binary.charCodeAt(i));
    }

    var blob = new Blob([new Uint8Array(array)], { type: 'audio/wav' });

    if (typeof window.navigator.msSaveBlob !== 'undefined') {
        window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, filename); 
    }else {
        var URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
        var downloadUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

        if (filename) {
            // use HTML5 a[download] attribute to specify filename
            var a = document.createElement("a");
            // safari doesn't support this yet
            if (typeof a.download === 'undefined') {
                window.location = downloadUrl;
            } else {
                a.href = downloadUrl;
                a.download = filename;
                document.body.appendChild(a);
                a.click();
            }
        } else {
            window.location = downloadUrl;
        }

        setTimeout(function () { URL.revokeObjectURL(downloadUrl); }, 100);
    }

}
```